# How to insert new row with id from other table in loop with Postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I would like to insert new row in `profit` table for each user that exist in db: `select id * from users`. The number of users is dynamic, so I need to fetch them all. I need some loop in postgres sql. I have problem to figure it out on my own. It would be something like that:

`select id * from users as user_ids`

```
for (each userId in user_ids) {
 insert into profit (user_id, value) values (userId, 23);
}
```

Can I ask You for help? I've went for many questions already:

[Insert new row with data computed from other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843969/insert-new-row-with-data-computed-from-other-rows)

[postgresSQL insert multiple rows, of id returned from select queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631914/postgressql-insert-multiple-rows-of-id-returned-from-select-queries)

No luck so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking in "loops" is almost always wrong when working with SQL. You need to think in terms of sets and how you operate on them. SQL statement describe exactly that: how to retrieve a set and what to do with that set of rows.

In this case, you can use a SELECT statement as the source for an INSERT:

```
insert into profit (user_id, value) 
select id, 23
from users;
```

Note that you don't have a `values` clause in this case.